# Why doesn't Python upcase special characters with upper()?

Tags: python, unicode

I don't get that:

```
'ô TRAM'.upper() != 'Ô TRAM'
'ô TRAM'.upper() == 'ô TRAM'
```

All text editors (including `vim` and `emacs`) convert 'ô TRAM'.upper() to 'Ô TRAM' when we ask for upcase. Why does Python seem to only upcase [a-zA-Z] characters? And what is the workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @Thanakon pointed out briefly is correct: You can do this on a **Unicode String**.

You did ask *why* Python does not do this on "narrow" strings, though. The reason is: Unicode is a really *huge* thing -- in terms of memory and processing. It is definitely **not trivial**. Take a look at the [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) definition or the implementation of the [ICU Library](http://site.icu-project.org/).

When Python was conceived, back in the early 90s, Unicode on strings was not a big issue yet. For the Python community **backwards compatibility** has always been a big concern. It therefore would have been very difficult to just do "unicode upcasing on narrow strings" in some 2.x version.

But other people were not satisfied with this solution in the 2000s, so they invented a **new data type**: `unicode`. If you put your data in there you get the full-fledged Unicode features. There are other modules for your convenience, too...

Oh, and by the way: The narrow string you showed has to be **interpreted in a codepage** before it makes sense to upcase it in unicode-ish. As your strings displays here it is *one* of many encoding interpretations (ISO-8859-1, maybe?)

But now the good thing: In **Python 3** they decided it's worth to break the backwards compatibility. The default string *is* a Unicode String then! When you write `'hello'` in Python 3 that is the same as in Python 2 `u'hello'`. And on that you get Unicode functionality.

Either way, in Python 2 with `u'blah'` or Python 3 `'blah'` you have to make sure the python-file is **saved in UTF-8** (or similar). In Python 3 it is the [standard encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/) of `*.py`-files, In Python 2 you have to [add an header-line](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` containing the files encoding, or make sure your editor writes the [UTF-8 BOM mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3, which uses Unicode by default, it should works.

In Python 2, you have to force it, this will do the trick:

```
u'ô TRAM'.upper()
```

**`u`** prevents the text to translate to ASCII. *(remaining as unicode)*

Answer (score 3):

You tagged your question as `unicode`, but you never made your string unicode:

```
>>> print u'ô TRAM'.upper()
Ô TRAM
>>> print 'ô TRAM'.upper()
ô TRAM
```